# PHP Database not Updating

Tags: php

I got 2 `isset()` in my **PHP** file. Adding new value is ok but in Updating the value seems working but not in database.

Here is my code for PHP.

```
<?php


if(isset($_POST['btnposins'])) { 
     mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
   //select database
 mysql_select_db("brm_dbs") or die(mysql_error());
$posi = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['inputposi']);
//insert data using insert into statement
 $query = "Insert into admin_position(Position)Values('$posi')";
  if (mysql_query($query)) {
 //dislay a message box that the saving is successfully save
 echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
        alert(\"New Position has been posted.\");
        window.location = \"new_admin.php\"
        </script>";

} else {
  echo("Failed: " . mysql_error());
} 

} 
else if(isset($_POST['btnposave'])) {
     mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
   //select database
 mysql_select_db("brm_dbs") or die(mysql_error());
$posid = $_POST['posid'];
$posname = $_POST['posname'];
//insert data using insert into statement
 $query = "UPDATE admin_positon SET Position='$posname' WHERE uid='$posid'";
                        //execute the query
                        mysql_query($query);
                            //header("Location: new_admin.php");
                            if (mysql_affected_rows() != 0) {
                            echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
                            alert(\"Position Name Edited\");
                            window.location = \"new_admin.php\"
                            </script>";
                        } else {
                            echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
                            alert(\"Position Name Not Edited\");
                            window.location = \"new_admin.php\"
                            </script>";
                        }

} else {

    echo 'No Tag'.mysql_error();
}


?>
```

What seems the problem in my code? its always returning **'Position Name Edited'** even my value is null.

And here is my Form

```
<div id="position"  class="modal" role="dialog">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
              <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                      <h4 class="modal-title">Posting New Position</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                      <form role="form" action="posi.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                          <fieldset>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                  <label>Position Name</label>
                                  <input id="inputposi" type="text" name="inputposi" class="form-control">
                              </div>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                  <table id="posi" class="table table-bordered table-hover ">
                          <thead>
                              <tr>
                                  <th>ID</th>
                                  <th>Position's</th>
                              </tr>
                                      </thead>
                                      <tbody id="posi">
                                  <?php
                            //set up mysql connection
                            mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
                            //select database
                            mysql_select_db("brm_dbs") or die(mysql_error());
                                    //select all records form tblmember table
                                    $query = 'SELECT * FROM admin_position';
                                    //execute the query using mysql_query
                                    $result = mysql_query($query);
                                   //then using while loop, it will display all the records inside the table
                                    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                                        echo ' <tr> ';
                                        echo ' <td> ';
                                        echo $row['uid'];
                                        echo ' <td> ';
                                        echo $row['Position'];
                                    }
                              ?>
                                      </tbody>
                                  </table>

                              </div>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                  <input type="number" id="posid" name="posid" placeholder="ID" class="form-control" >
                                  <input type="text" id="posname" name="posname" placeholder="Desired Position Name" class="form-control" >
                              </div>
                              <div class="modal-footer">
                                  <button type="submit" id="btnposave" name="btnposave" onclick="edit()" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
                                  <button type="submit" id="btnposins" name="btnposins" onclick="edit()" class="btn btn-success">ADD</button>
                                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                              </div>
                          </fieldset>
                      </form>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
```

**UPDATED**
It seems the `$_POST['posid']` AND `$_POST['posname']` is not passing a value. whats causing this? Help please.

Comment: From where you are getting posid and posname.  <input type="number" id="posid" name="posid" placeholder="ID" class="form-control" >
                                  <input type="text" id="posname" name="posname" placeholder="Desired Position Name" class="form-control" >. You are not setting the value over here

Comment: You should really try to use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php) MySQL_* functions are deprecated, and in PHP 7 have been approved to removal...

Comment: @raveenanigam what do you mean that i'm not setting the value?

Comment: Try to optimize your code. There is no need to set db connection all the time. use error_reporting(E_ALL); to check what you are missing

Comment: tried your code but returned **32767**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this:

```
if (mysql_affected_rows() != 0) // OR change to !== 0
```

to this:

```
if (mysql_affected_rows() == 1) {
```

Comment: thanks but something in my code don't recognizing the value of `[postid] and [posname]`

Comment: the problem is that you have 2 input types submit with name on it you have to use javascript or separate form ADD of form Update:  <button type="submit" id="btnposave" name="btnposave" onclick="edit()" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
                                  <button type="submit" id="btnposins" name="btnposins" onclick="edit()" class="btn btn-success">ADD</button>

Comment: I'm aware of that, thats why I use isset for separate function

Comment: the correct way is: `code`<form method="post"><input type="hidden" name="order" value="Save"></form> and form 2: <form method="post"><input type="hidden" name="order" value="Add"></form>`code`

Comment: even if use isset name value is on the same form tags <form></form> you'll need 2 forms to do this or use javascript to create a post

Comment: and do: if (isset($_POST['order']) && $_POST['order'] == 'Save') {echo 'save stuff';} else if (isset($_POST['order']) && $_POST['order'] == 'Add') {echo 'Insert stuff to DB';}

Comment: with a small javascript: 1- Add an id to the form. id="MyForm" and add add() btnposins; and save() btnposave to your onclick event. 2- Remove name="btnposins" , name="btnposave" and substitute type="submit" for input type="button" 3- Add this javascript to the bottom of you page: `<script type="text/javascript">function add() {document.getElementById("btnposins").name='btnposins'; document.getElementById("MyForm").submit();} function save() {document.getElementById("btnposave").name='btnposave'; document.getElementById("MyForm").submit();}</script>`